# AttributeError - 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, attributeerror

I keep getting an error in `posts = Post.published.all()`

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
     ('draft','Draft'),
     ('published','Published'),
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                         unique_for_date='published')
author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                           related_name='blog_posts',
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField()
published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                          choices = STATUS_CHOICES,
                          default='draft')
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                   args=[self.publish.year,
                         self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                         self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                         self.slug])

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-published',)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
posts = Post.published.all()
return render(request,
              'blog/post/list.html',
              {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                               status='published',
                               publish_year=year,
                               publish_month=month,
                               publish_day=day)
```

And I keep getting this error whenever i run my server...

`AttributeError at /blog/
'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'all'`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
def post_list(request):
posts = Post.published.all() ...
```

Also some tips to make my own blog page would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `objects` instead of `published`

```
posts = Post.objects.all()
```

If you want to filter `published` post then use this:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(status='published')
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it  work with the custom Published Manager add this on top of the post  class in your models file.

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
        self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')
```

Then add the manager inside the Post class

> published = PublishedManager()

Answer (score 0):

To get all the posts:

```
posts = Post.objects.all()
```

To get the published posts:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(status='published')
```